# How can I convert a number into another with $\mod 315$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't know how to convert $1838$ into a number that has $\mod 315$

Basically:

$1838 = x \mod 315 $

I need to know how to find that $x$. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get an answer rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. What do you know about congruence? Could you find $38 \pmod {10}$?

Comment: Are you looking for $1838\mod 315$? Because $x\mod 315$ is $<315$ hence cannot be equal $1838>315$.

Comment: $x$ is the remainder when you divide $1838$ by $315$.

Comment: What is wrong with $x=1838$? It is certainly true that $1838=1838\bmod 315$.